# I am having trouble reaching a ninth. Best way to practise?

Tags: piano

This is my first question so apologies for any mistakes.

I am having trouble with a particular bar in a piece, where my hand has to reach from the second B to the first C and again from the second C to the first D.[image]

What's the best way to play these notes and is there anything I can do with regards to hand movements? Any videos or images would be appreciated.

**Piece:** La dispute - Yann Tiersen

Comment: Can you hold down a ninth with your right hand? If you can, things should be easier for you. If you can't, things will be understandably harder. For the matter, I can barely hit a ninth as long as both notes are on white or black keys, but then I'm guaranteed to hit adjacent notes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't have to span a ninth to play this if it were simply octaves, right? Well, this passage isn't any different. Do **not** try to hold down the lower note while reaching for the next upper one. Straining your hand through overextending can be harmful and is usually not even a good way of playing such passages.

Instead, practice playing the passage as octaves until you've got the wrist movement down. *Then* add the slight rotational movement to turn the octaves into downwards arpeggios.

Comment: Would this mean I would have play each downward arpeggio fairly lightly, so I can play the bar evenly?